# Linking Related Entities in EF

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

i have two entities- Project and ProjectType

Project has -ID,TypeID,name
ProjectType has - ID,name

TypeId is the foreign key between Project and ProjectType table

now say I have an object on hand after doing something like below

```
var selprojtype = db.ProjectTypes.Single(p => p.Name == id);
```

then I say I am creating a new project which I want to link to the project type

```
Project project = new Project();
```

if I do

```
project.ProjectType = selprojtype;
```

the TypeId not set. So I always end up exclusively setting foreign keys as below before calling the SaveChanges method.

```
project.TypeId= selprojecttype.ID
```

Is there a better way to link related entities?

Comment: You don't need to set the foreign key property `TypeId`. EF will store the correct FK when you save the changes.

Comment: It doesnt hence the question.

Comment: Do you get an exception when you call `SaveChanges`? Can you show the full context of your code up to SaveChanges and the model classes? Do you use `DbContext` or `ObjectContext`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you establish relation between objects, both the objects have to be in the same data context. So your code should read:

```
var selprojtype = db.ProjectTypes.Single(p => p.Name == id);
Project project = new Project();

//now add newly created project object to the context
db.Projects.Attach(project);

//now establish the relation
 project.ProjectType=selprojtype;
```

Comment: if there aren't any records in the database with the given id this code will throw an exception: db.ProjectTypes.Single(p => p.Name == id). it should be SingleOrDefault just in case which returns null if there aren't any records with the given id.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this:

```
public int? TypeId { get; set; }
private ProjectType projectType;
public ProjectType ProjectType{
    get { return projectType;}
    set {
          projectType = value;
          TypeId = value != null ? value.Id : null;
        }
}
```

This way you control the FK directly when you assign the relation.